# Reload data after state transition

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have a problem after calling the $state.transitionTo method.

$state.transitionTo('example', {}, { reload: true});

When I access my view in the first time, the data is correctly loaded. If I manually go back in my application and try to access the same page, the data is reloaded.
But, when I call the $state.transitionTo, the code inside the controller is not executed and myList is not updated.

Here is the code for the controller.

```
        .controller('ExampleCtrl', function 
                   ($scope, $state, $stateParams, Service) {

               $scope.myList= {};

               var exampleCtrl = $scope;
               ProdutorService.findAllData($scope.example.idExample).then(function(data){
                      exampleCtrl.myList = data;
               });
         }
```

I think that it might be related to this bug in the $state.reload():
(bug with controllers reinstantiating right now, fixing soon).
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#statereload

Is there any option to enforce executing the controller code or to call a controller function after the state transition?

I am using angularjs with ionic and cordova. It is a mobile application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

The responsible for the caching was the ionic framework.

By default, Ionic caches all the views for performance. In order to avoid that, it is needed to add a cache:false in the state definition.

```
        .state('example', {
            url: "/example",
            templateUrl: 'templates/example.html',
            controller: 'ExampleCtrl',
            cache: false
        })
```

This way, my data is being refreshed.

Comment: +1 because you've made things better. However I have a similar issue and something else is going on. Most of the time page transitions work, then suddenly they stop working - once one fails they all fail and the page has to be refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the `$ionicView.enter` listener to update the data, this way the whole view will not need to be recreated.

Scroll Down to View Lifecycle in [this blog post](http://ionicframework.com/blog/navigating-the-changes/)